# Determine list indices of Outliers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, outliers

I found that it is possibly using `numpy` and `where` conditional statements on array to receive their indices and I know that in box plots (e.g. `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots().boxplot(...,showfliers=False,...)`) the definition of a flier which I interpret as "outlier" is given as the 1./3. Quartile +- 1.5 * IQR (Inter Quartile Range) as can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)

Since I have two independent lists (e.g. x, y) of the same size it would be necessary to remove the outliers from list x and the elements with the same indices from list y or zip the list and work on them.

Proposal that needs improvement towards determining the fliers:

```
xy = list(zip(x,y))
xy = [(i,j) for i, j in xy\
    if (1. Quartile - 1.5 IQR) < i < (3. Quartile + 1.5 IQR)]
bp.append(ax.scatter(\
    list(zip(*xy))[0],\
    list(zip(*xy))[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If x and y are `np.array` types then you can do this:

```
quartile = ...
IQR = ...
# Here, I'm guess what you're attempting to do with these equations.
lower = (1. * quartile - 1.5 * IQR)
upper = (3. * quartile + 1.5 * IQR)
idx = np.where( (lower < x) & (x < upper) )

xs_without_outliers = x[idx]
ys_without_outliers = x[idx]

ax.scatter(xs_without_outliers, ys_without_outliers)
```

Here, idx are the indexes from `x` that meet the given condition. So we can get the values of why that correspond to the values of x that meet the condition with `y[idx]`.